# Retain ViewModels with fragment scope while rotating screen

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-components

We are using support libs `v 25.+` and the new architecture components `v 1.0.0-alpha3` and we recognized that the ViewModels that are Fragment scoped are not correctly retained:

```
class MyFragment : LifecycleFragment() {

    protected lateinit var viewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    }
}
```

The viewModel is basically recreated every single time the app rotates. This can be solved by changing to `onActivityCreated` as used in the google examples. 
Since the documentation points out to use `onCreate` I expect this is a fragment or `ViewModelProvider` bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After consulting with the Android team we figured out that it is indeed an issue within the `SupportFragmentManager` which is solved in `v 26.+` so switching to

```
26.0.0-beta2
```

helped and now ViewModels are retained in `onCreate` as expected.